# How to create public accessible directory?

Tags: windows-10, directory

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 in Windows LAN.
How can I create a directory which will be accessible (RW) for any application running on Windows workstation (Everyone in Windows) in the LAN. What permissions should be?

I have created directory, shared it for group()
. In Windows I see it but when try to open: you do not have permissions

Answer (score 0):

for the windows to ubuntu side:
right click in windows explorer -> New -> Folder
Name it something like "Public_LAN_Share"
right click -> properties
sharing tab
drop-down -> everyone
add
drop-down (next to read) -> read/write
share
"yes turn on ..."
done
right click folder -> properties
sharing tab
"advanced sharing"
check "Share this folder"
permissions
check allow for "full control"
apply
ok
ok
close
logout, then login

Comment: It is in Ubuntu?

Comment: sorry, I read the question wrong, this is the other way around. for putting a share on the ubuntu machine that's visible to the windows machines, you'll need to setup an smb server / service, this guide here looks pretty good: https://itsfoss.com/share-folders-local-network-ubuntu-windows/

Comment: NP. thanx, will try